# How to deal with old questions with wrong answers?

Tags: discussion

So, we got a [question on the old myth of heating the pan](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/99543/why-do-you-need-to-heat-the-pan-before-heating-the-olive-oil) before adding oil today.  This question is a duplicate of [a much older question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/do-you-heat-the-pan-first-then-add-oil-or-put-the-oil-in-and-heat-up-with-the), of course.

However, there's a problem: the accepted answer for the older question is wrong, and for that matter an objectively bad answer.  Yet, on the new question we're getting votes to close as duplicate ... which means its very possible that the new question, with a better-researched answer, will get closed and folks on the site will continue to get referred to the old, wrong answer (yes, I have a vested interest because it's *my* answer, but this is hardly the only such case).

I know this is a chronic problem across StackExchange, where many wrong answers have become canonical because they were given early in the site's history.  But how do we want to deal with it on SA?

Should answerers who discover an old bad answer go back and add a new answer to the old question?  How would that answer ever become accepted, given that the old asker is long gone?  Is there a way to vote to "not close"?

Comment: Mods can remove the accept mark if you flag it. If it's objectively bad, try flagging it and explain in a custom message.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that would be called for in this instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We ended up discussing this on the question I linked.  Consensus is: close the old poor answer as a duplicate.

Leaving this here for posterity.